# C++ breaks out of the loop when filling the array

Tags: c++, for-loop, if-statement, multidimensional-array, while-loop

So basically I am trying to create a loop that fills a matrix with random numbers. I need to make it so every column has a different range, unique to it.

```
    //Variables
    int lsx = 3;
    int lsy = 10;
    int lust[lsy][lsx];
    int i = 0;
    int l = 0;
    int shpp = 7;
    //List setup
    for (i = 0; i < lsy; i++)
    {
        for (l = 0; l < lsx; l++)
        {
            lust[i][l] = 0;
        }
    }
    while (true)
    {
        //List generator
        for (i = 0; i < lsy; i++)
        {
            for (l = 0; l < lsx; l++)
            {
                //Column 1
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    lust[i][l] = rand() % flx;
                    cout << lust[i][l] << '\n';
                }
                //Column 2
                if (i == 1)
                {
                    lust[i][l] = rand() % fly;
                    cout << lust[i][l] << '\n';
                }
                //Column 3
                if (i == 2)
                {
                    lust[i][l] = rand() % shpp;
                    cout << lust[i][l] << '\n';
                }
            }
            cout << "Endline reached! \n \n";
        }
        for (i = 0; i < lsy; i++)
        {
            for (l = 0; l < lsx; l++)
            {
                cout << lust[i][l] << " ";
            }
            cout << "\n";
        }
    }   
}
```

This only generates 3 lines. Does anyone have any ideas on why this could happen?
I tried changing some stuff around but only got weirder results that wouldn't fill the array in completely either[This is what the program displays when I try and run it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80shY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (l = 0; l < lsx; l++)
    {
    Column 1
    if (i == 0)
    }
    lust[i][l] = rand() % flx;
    cout << lust[i][l] << '\n';
    }
    Column 2
    if (i == 1)
    }
    lust[i][l] = rand() % fly;
    cout << lust[i][l] << '\n';
    }
    Column 3
    if (i == 2)
    {
    lust[i][l] = rand() % shpp;
    cout << lust[i][l] << '\n';
    }
}
cout << "Endline reached! \n \n";
```

You're using i (the line iterator) to evaluate what you're going to fill. Which means your code will only concern itself with lines 0, 1 and 2. Instead, shift that i to l - your column iterator. It should work.

Also, consider removing the while true loop. Not only is it redundant, it's also pretty dangerous considering there's no break condition - in this case it's safe, since you'll be around to shut it down, but as a good practice stay out of while(true) unless you can't write your break condition as a boolean expression

Comment: Thank you! It did fix the issue at hand. It is a part of a larger program which is why the while loop is there. I didn't think it was part of the problem but left it in just in case

Comment: It wasn't, but while(true) is always "risky" hehe. Since it's integrated it's fine tho ^^